# Php beginner code doesn't work. Any ideas?

Tags: php

I'm trying to learn php, but when I try to compile this code

```
<?php

  $n = 15,32;
  $log = log ($n);

  printf ("log (%0.2f) = %.5<br>", $log);

?>
```

it shows me

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ','on line 25

but when I try to compile this

```
<?php

  $n = 15.32;
  $log = log ($n);

  printf ("log (%0.2f) = %.5<br>", $log);

?>
```

it doesn't print anything. Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) at the top of your file(s): `ini_set("display_errors", 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` and you will also get a warning for the second code. Then it will be clear what you have to fix :)

Comment: and for the first piece of code,  php uses the period (full-stop) decimal separator for integers